# custom XML part is getting replaced in co-authoring mode

Tags: ms-word, onedrive, office-addins, collaborative-editing

I'm using `onedrive for business` for co-authoring the document, provided that, My document contains customXML, which is mapped with document object.

Now, when two user edits the plain text, their changes are saved in real-time. But when user edits the CustomXML (which is mapped with document), one whose changes are saved at last will replace the changes saved previously.

Technically, changes in document.xml are saved in real time or we must say that the document.xml of two users are getting merged but the customXML are getting completely replaced, instead, they should be merged.

Can anyone help me that how to support the co-authoring of content control?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Your issue appears to be end-user related.

Comment: @CindyMeister, this is not an end user issue. I'm facing the problem with merging of customXML part of a word document (docx document). This is a legit programming related issue.

Answer (score 2):

CustomXML data gets lost when multiple users are co-authoring on the same document (Tested with Excel and Word). This means that CustomXML is not supported in combination with co-authoring. Does microsoft plan to solve this for Excel and Word?

The problem is that CustomXML is not synced during co-authoring. CustomXML is only saved when actively pressing save or closing the document.

So when multiple people are working on the same document, first person adds CustomXML and closes the document, a second user can now hard save their version of the workbook aswell. The added CustomXML will be lost.